# Neo4j (4.1.3) : How to create relationship on the fly when match returns exactly one row for one label

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j 4.1.3. I have 2 labels : Person and Rec. I need to create a relationship between these 2 only when there exists exactly one person with that last name. When I run the below, relationships are created for all persons with that last name. My code is below:

```
MATCH (echk:REC {id: 'abcdef'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Person) WHERE  p.name CONTAINS 'Shirley' 
WITH p, echk, count(p) as personcnt 
where  personcnt=1
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(p, 'Test', {}, {}, echk, {}) YIELD rel
RETURN p, echk, rel
```

I have 33 people with "Shirley' and 33 relationships are getting created with that REC. However, there should be no relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Run this

```
MATCH (echk:REC {id: 'abcdef'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Person) WHERE  p.name CONTAINS 'Shirley' 
RETURN p, echk, count(p) as personcnt
```

and you'll see why all 33 are created.

If there can only be one match, I suggest trying to find the "one" Shirley first, if they don't exist you are done, if more than one you are done.  If and only if only one match returns, then continue on to match with 'abcdef' and do the merge.

Comment: I do not know how many matches will be there. It could be anywhere from 0 match to any number. However, per my logic, I need to process only when there is a single match.

Answer (score 0):

If I have both p and count(p) in the WITH, I always get 1 for count(p) which makes sense. So I have changed my query as below to make this to work:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Person) WHERE  p.name CONTAINS 'Shirley'
WITH count(p) AS cnt WHERE cnt = 1
  MATCH (echk:REC {id: 'abcdef'})
  MATCH (p:Person) where p.name contains 'Shirley'
  CALL apoc.merge.relationship(p, 'Test', {}, {}, echk, {}) yield rel
```

I have now added this to my cypher logic to create dynamic relationship and it works as expected. Hopefully this helps someone at a later date.